# Is there a term which describes objects with coflat diagonal?

Tags: ct.category-theory

As the topic says, I wonder if there is already a term which describes objects $L$ whose diagaonal $\Delta_{L}:L\to L\times L$ is coflat, where, by 'coflat' I mean 'preserves epis under pullback'.

Comment: I'm just curious: In which categories do you want to consider such a notion? Have you looked at Yves Diers' *Categories of Commutative Algebras*?

Comment: I have.  I've missed things before, and I may be now.  I'll take a look again.  
I do know that if the object in question was an arrow then Diers (and lots of other people) would call that arrow etale.  My situation is a little different in that I'm interested in objects whose diagonal is coflat and I'm interested in this property outside of Zariski categories.

Thank you for taking a look at this, though, Martin.